# how to link css file from outside web application

Tags: css, .net, hyperlink, parent

Simple as title says, how do I include a css file that is found two parent folders up from the actual web application itself?

I have tried adding the file as a link to the web project and then referencing it like that and it dose not work

Answer (score 0):

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../mystyle.css" />` would literally move up two folders on your server. You may be better off with using the full path: `<linke rel="stylesheet" href="/folder1/folder2/mystyle.css" />` - which all assumes that the path you need to get to is accessible to the web server.

Comment: i try it like this <link href="../../sharedFiles/css/MainCss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> and it does not work , says i cannot use ../.. for going up directories

Comment: That's not a very clear error message, but you should also be able to start with a `/` to start at the root of the web server and use the absolute path to your file: `/directory/subdirectory/sharedFiles/css/MainCss.css` - if that doesn't work, the folder is not accessible from the web server.

Answer (score 0):

Since the page comes from the server I would read the physical file and stuff that onto the page as part of the server script such as:

```
<style>
<?= css_file_content ?>
</style>
```

If in a parent folder, it may be outside the hosted path making it inaccessible to the client. But it is not inaccessible to the server-side script.

Comment: please delete this comment

Answer (score 0):

Visit: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

You can add inline css if external doesn't work